# Open GL Android 3D Object Rotation Issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, rotation

I am having trouble rotating my 3D objects in Open GL. I start each draw frame by loading the identity (glLoadIdentity()) and then I push and pop on the stack according to what I need (for the camera, etc). I then want 3D objects to be able to roll, pitch and yaw and then have them displayed correctly.

Here is the catch... I want to be able to do incremental rotations as if I was flying an airplane. So every time the up button is pushed the object rotates around it's own x axis. But then if the object is pitched down and chooses to yaw, the rotation should then be around the object's up vector and not the Y axis.

I've tried doing the following: 


**glRotatef(pitchTotal, 1,0,0);

glRotatef(yawTotal, 0,1,0);

glRotate(rollTotal, 0,0,1);**



and those don't seem to work. (Keeping in mind that the vectors are being computed correctly)
I've also tried...
**glRotatef(pitchTotal, 1,0,0);

glRotatef(yawTotal, 0,1,0);

glRotate(rollTotal, 0,0,1);**


 and I still get weird rotations.
Long story short... **What is the proper way to rotate a 3D object in Open GL using the object's look, right and up vector?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. The first response pointed me in the right direction, the second response helped a little too, but ultimately it boiled down to a combination of both. Initially, your 3D object should have a member variable which is a float array size 16. [0-15]. You then have to initialize it to the identity matrix. Then the member methods of your 3D object like "yawObject(float amount)" just know that you are yawing the object from "the objects point of view" and not the world, which would allow the incremental rotation. Inside the yawObject method (or pitch,roll ojbect) you need to call the Matrix.rotateM(myfloatarray,0,angle,0,1,0). That will store the new rotation matrix (as describe in the first response). You can then when you are about to draw your object, multiply the model matrix by the myfloatarray matrix using gl.glMultMatrix.

Good luck and let me know if you need more information than that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the yaw rotation around (around Y) **before** you do the pitch one. Otherwise, the pitch will be off.

E.g. you have a 45 degrees downward pitch and a 180 degrees yaw. By doing the pitch first, and then rotate the yaw around the airplane's Y vector, the airplane would end up pointing up and backwards despite the pitch being downwards. By doing the yaw first, the plane points backwards, then the pitch around the plane's X vector will make it point downwards correctly.

The same logic applies for roll, which needs to be applied last.

So your code should be :

```
glRotatef(yawTotal, 0,1,0);
glRotatef(pitchTotal, 1,0,0);
glRotatef(rollTotal, 0,0,1);
```

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake, the second group of glRotates should have  been around the up, right, and look vectors. I tried rearranging the vectors and my object is still not rotating correctly. It works fore 90 degree angles pretty well. In other words, I can fly my object around by incrimenting the roll,pitch, and yaw by 90 degrees, but that doesn't always work (only some time) and then it gets crazy if I try to do small increments... Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Cumulative rotations will suffer from gimbal lock. Look at it this way: suppose you are in an aeroplane, flying level. You apply a yaw of 90 degrees anticlockwise. You then apply a roll of 90 degrees clockwise. You then apply a yaw of 90 degrees clockwise.

Your plane is now pointing straight downward — the total effect is a pitch of 90 degrees clockwise. But if you just tried to add up the different rotations then you'd end up with a roll of 90 degrees, and no pitch whatsoever because you at no point applied pitch to the plane.

Trying to store and update rotation as three separate angles doesn't work.

Common cited solutions are to use a quaternion or to store the object orientation directly as a matrix. The matrix solution is easier to build because you can prototype it with OpenGL's built-in matrix stacks. Most people also seem to find matrices easier to understand than quaternions.

So, assuming you want to go matrix, your prototype might do something like (please forgive my lack of decent Java knowledge; I'm going to write C essentially):

```
GLfloat myOrientation[16];

// to draw the object:
glMultMatrixf(myOrientation);
/* drawing here */

// to apply roll, assuming the modelview stack is active:
glPushMatrix();                    // backup what's already on the stack
    glLoadIdentity();              // start with the identity
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    glMultMatrixf(myOrientation);  // premultiply the current orientation by the roll

    // update our record of orientation
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, myOrientation);
glPopMatrix();
```

You possibly don't want to use the OpenGL stack in shipping code because it's not really built for this sort of use and so performance may be iffy. But you can prototype and profile rather than making an assumption. You also need to consider floating point precision problems — really you should be applying a step that ensures myOrientation is still orthonormal after it has been adjusted.

It's probably easiest to check Google for that, but briefly speaking you'll use the dot product to remove erroneous crosstalk from two of the axes to the third, then to remove from one of the first two axes from the second, then renormalise all three.